# hybris - one to many and many to many relationship

Tags: database, sap-commerce-cloud, datamodel, commerce

In our production sytem, we have an existing relationship which is *one to many*. We would like to change this relationship to *many to many* due to business/data reasons.

What steps we need to take without loosing data and with no impact to production data, as we need to change *-items.xml file within hybris system.

Appreciate your inputs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database structure for one-to-many and many-to-many is different. One-to-many records uses 1 table (the many records are saved in the one table), but many-to-many uses an extra table.

I suggest to export existing data, update the items.xml (with platform update), and reimport the data.